# Python коверкает эти данные в строках (заменяет цифры в текстовой строке на другие символы)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здравствуете! Я хотел автоматизировать обработку кучи .psd файлов с помощью PSDImage, для этого мне было нужно обработать массив путей до этих файлов. Проблема заключается в том, что Python коверкает эти данные.

Например, есть файл расположенный по адресу:

J:\1. Работа\Доска почета 91\Доска почета на 2018 50Гб\Портреты на доску почета\1445\DSC_1453.psd

Но на выходе получается это:

J:☺. Работа\Доска почета 91\Доска почета на 2018 50Гб\Портреты на доску почетаd5\DSC_1453.psd

Собственно сам код (я удалил из него всё лишнее, что бы вычленить эти проблему):

```
from psd_tools import PSDImage

tmp = u'J:\1. Работа\Доска почета 91\Доска почета на 2018 50Гб\Портреты на доску почета\1445\DSC_1453.psd'

print (tmp)
```

Я пробовал писать u"...", пробовал указывать "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" и даже пробовал сохранять .py файл в различных кодировках через блокнот. Ничего не помогает. при этом я и раньше писал скрипты используя пути до файлов, но такой проблемы раньше не возникало.

Comment: `\1` это управляющая последовательность. Будьте аккуртнее с обратными косыми. Их стоит экранировать `J:\\1. `

Comment: Спасибо! Я заменил '\' на '\\' и всё заработало. А затем я и вовсе прописал замену tmp = tmp.replace(u'\\', u'\\\\')

Comment: Виндовые пути удобнее через `r`-строку задавать, меньше проблем. `r'J:\1. Работа\Доска почета 91\Доска почета на 2018 50Гб\Портреты на доску почета\1445\DSC_1453.psd'`.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `/` как разделитель каталогов для путей - это работет на всех современных ОС.

Для остальных лучший выход использовать `os.path.join('c:', 'dir', 'file.txt')`

Comment: К сожалению, современные ОС не везде :)

Comment: @МихаилМуругов у Вас Виндовс XP или DOS? Могу проверить на Висте.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов дополнил крассплатформенным способом.

Comment: Или с помощью более молодёжного pathlib.Path('c').joinpath('dir', 'file.txt')

Comment: @Alpensin делить путь прикольно, но по мне как баловство

Comment: Почему-то вариант со "/" в качестве разделителя не сработал. Программа выполнилась без ошибок, но файл в нужной директории так и не был создан.